# DictReader, No quotes, tabbed file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:
Please note, there are no quotes, a tab (\t) is the delimiter, and there is a blank line between the header and the actual content.

```
Facility No     Testing No      Name    Age

252     2351    Jackrabbit, Jazz        15
345     257     Aardvark, Ethel 41
```

I think I've tried nearly every possible combination of ideas and parameters

```
f = open('/tmp/test', 'r')
csvFile = f.read()
reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
print reader.fieldnames
```

the result of the print is:

```
['F']
```

How can I get this into something I can parse to put into a database?
Getting it into a dictionary would be helpful.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

What is your `csvFile`? Is it a string representing your filename starting with 'F'?

`csv.DictReader` needs an opened file object, not a filename.

Try:

```
with open(csvFile, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    print reader.fieldnames
```

**EDIT**

If your `csvFile` is a string containing the whole data, you will have to convert it into a `StringIO` (because `csv` can access only file-like objects, not strings).

Try:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

# csvFile = 'Facility No\tTesting No\tName\tAge\n\n252\t2351\tJackrabbit, Jazz\t15\n345\t257\tAardvark, Ethel\t41\n'
reader = csv.DictReader(StringIO(csvFile), delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
print reader.fieldnames
```

Or, if your edited question opens and reads a file:

```
with open('/tmp/test', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    print reader.fieldnames
```

This works for me.

Comment: csvFile is actually a string. I used urllib2 to get the file from a website by doing a response.read(), now I want to chop it up and put it into a database. csvFile has the whole file in it. I am still only getting that ['F']

Comment: yeah, I do have an opened file, not just the filename

Comment: @Mike, see my EDIT, convert the string into StringIO.

Comment: @Mike: If you have `response` object then you could pass it directly to the `DictReader`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360932/dictreader-no-quotes-tabbed-file/5367501#5367501

Comment: always use `'rb'` (binary) mode for files that you pass to `csv` module.

Answer (score 2):

this might work for you, at least as a start:

```
>>> import csv
>>> input = open('/tmp/csvtemp.csv')
>>> csvin = csv.reader(input, delimiter='\t')
>>> data = [row for row in csvin]
>>> header = data.pop(0)
>>> data.pop(0)  # skip blank line
[]
>>> for row in data:
...  rowdict = dict(zip(header, row))
...  print rowdict
... 
{'Age': '15', 'Testing No': '2351', 'Name': 'Jackrabbit, Jazz', 'Facility No': '252'}
{'Age': '41', 'Testing No': '257', 'Name': 'Aardvark, Ethel', 'Facility No': '345'}
```

Comment: @eumiro: agreed, that is probably the primary problem.

Comment: `csv` works with blank lines as is without additional manipulations. Try `print list(csv.DictReader(inputfile, dialect=csv.excel_tab))` [`inputfile` should be opened in binary mode `'rb'`].  btw, `input()` is a builtin function, don't shadow it.

Comment: the best answer so far! thanks @jcomeau_ictx for the dict answer. I always hated csv libraries, never found the perfect one!

Answer (score 1):

[From the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360932/dictreader-no-quotes-tabbed-file/5360978#5360978) I understand that you get your data via `urllib2`. `response` is a file-like object; you could pass it directly to `csv.DictReader`:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
reader = csv.DictReader(response, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```