# Combining multiple CSV file into a single one

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have CSV files in which Data is formatted as follows:

**file1.csv**

```
ID,NAME
001,Jhon
002,Doe
```

**fille2.csv**

```
ID,SCHOOLS_ATTENDED
001,my Nice School
002,His lovely school
```

**file3.csv**

```
ID,SALARY
001,25
002,40
```

*ID* field is kind of primary key that will be used to fetch record.

What is the most efficient way to read 3 to 4 files and get corresponding data and store in another CSV file having headings (ID,NAME,SCHOOLS_ATTENDED,SALARY)?

The file sizes are in the hundreds of MBs (100, 200 Mb).

Comment: Why someone will downvote it???

Comment: Perhaps because it shows a lack of research effort on your part? It wasn't me, though.

Comment: I think it's a duplicate question. You should always search it before open a new question. BTW, It wasn't me!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586573/python-combing-data-from-different-csv-files-into-one/17588521#17588521

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hundreds of megabytes aren't that much. Why not go for a simple approach using the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(dict)
fieldnames = {"ID"}

for csvfile in ("file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv"):
    with open(csvfile, newline="") as infile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
        for row in reader:
            id = row.pop("ID")
            for key in row:
                fieldnames.add(key) # wasteful, but I don't care enough
                result[id][key] = row[key]
```

The resulting `defaultdict` looks like this:

```
>>> result
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, 
{'001': {'SALARY': '25', 'SCHOOLS_ATTENDED': 'my Nice School', 'NAME': 'Jhon'},
'002': {'SALARY': '40', 'SCHOOLS_ATTENDED': 'His lovely school', 'NAME': 'Doe'}})
```

You could then combine that into a CSV file (not my prettiest work, but good enough for now):

```
with open("out.csv", "w", newline="") as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, sorted(fieldnames))
    writer.writeheader()
    for item in result:
        result[item]["ID"] = item
        writer.writerow(result[item])
```

`out.csv` then contains

```
ID,NAME,SALARY,SCHOOLS_ATTENDED
001,Jhon,25,my Nice School
002,Doe,40,His lovely school
```

Comment: Thanks but your code gives error **csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)***

Comment: @Volatil3: I only just noticed that you're on Python 3; I have already edited the program accordingly. Please try again.

Comment: I just noticed that the Delimiter is ** ~**

Comment: I am trying this thing(http://stackoverflow.com/a/5360978/275002) but seems Python 3 does not support it anymore?

Comment: You can specify a different delimiter: `open(csvfile, newline="", delimiter="~")`

Comment: with open(csvfile, newline="", delimiter="~") as infile:
TypeError: 'delimiter' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Ah, drat, that was a brainfart. Sorry. It must be `reader = csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter="~")` instead, of course.

Comment: Now getting this:    **id = row.pop("ID")**
**KeyError: 'ID'**  Though ID is right there.  Though NOT the first Field

Comment: Actually in one field it is mentioned **ID** while in other it is mentioned as *id* (in Small) thus breaking code. How to overcome it other than changing actual File?

Comment: You could force all keys to uppercase by the `.upper()` method. Then you won't get any collisions.

Comment: This is what I did now it screwed up and gives MEMORY ERROR as I loadded up a 140MB file

Comment: How much memory do you have? Are you on a 64bit system?

Comment: 32bit based Windows 7

Comment: OK what I figured, I got memory error when I tried to print **result** otherwise no Memory error

Answer (score 0):

Following is the working code for combining multiple csv files with specific keywords in their names into 1 final csv file. I have set the default keyword to "file" but u can set it blank if u want to combine all csv files from a folder_path. This code will take header from your first csv file and use it as a header in final combined csv file. It will ignore headers of all other csv files.

```
import glob,os
@staticmethod
def Combine_multiple_csv_files_thatContainsKeywordInTheirNames_into_one_csv_file(folder_path,keyword='file'):
    #takes header only from 1st csv, all other csv headers are skipped and data is appened to final csv

    fileNames = glob.glob(folder_path + "*" + keyword + "*"+".csv")  # fileNames INCLUDES FOLDER_PATH TOO
    with open(folder_path+"Combined_csv.csv", "w", newline='') as fout:
        print('Combining multiple csv files into 1')
        csv_write_file = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=',')
        # a.writerows(op)
        with open(fileNames[0], mode='rt')  as read_file:  # utf8
            csv_read_file = csv.reader(read_file, delimiter=',')  # CSVREADER READS FILE AS 1 LIST PER ROW. SO WHEN WRITIN TO ANOTHER  CSV FILE WITH FUNCTION WRITEROWS, IT INTRODUCES ANOTHER NEW LINE '\N' CHARACTER. SO TO AVOID DOUBLE NEWLINES , WE SET NEWLINE AS '' WHEN WE OPEN CSV WRITER OBJECT
            csv_write_file.writerows(csv_read_file)

        for num in range(1, len(fileNames)):
            with open(fileNames[num], mode='rt')  as read_file:  # utf8
                csv_read_file = csv.reader(read_file, delimiter=',')  # CSVREADER READS FILE AS 1 LIST PER ROW. SO WHEN WRITIN TO ANOTHER  CSV FILE WITH FUNCTION WRITEROWS, IT INTRODUCES ANOTHER NEW LINE '\N' CHARACTER. SO TO AVOID DOUBLE NEWLINES , WE SET NEWLINE AS '' WHEN WE OPEN CSV WRITER OBJECT
                next(csv_read_file) # ignore header
                csv_write_file.writerows(csv_read_file)
```